# Two prepositions of time together (e.g. "until after") to express a time point

Tags: prepositions, time

> I didn't think about it **until after** my Ceremony of Twelve.
>
> I didn't think about it **before** my Ceremony of Twelve.

I have seen many times *two* prepositions of time together. Do they express a point in time more precisely? How the time point expressed in the first sentence differ from the second?

Comment: Also, the second one does not actually specify that you thought about it at all. It just implies it. Using until means that you did think about it.

Comment: What is a "Ceremony of Twelve"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't think about it before my Ceremony of Twelve.

This is a very simple statement; whatever *it* is, you did not think of it before the Ceremony of Twelve. It says absolutely nothing about whether or not you thought of it *after* the ceremony; you might have and you might not have, but no implication is made either way (without further context, at any rate).

> I didn't think about it until after my Ceremony of Twelve.

This means that you *did* think about it at some point, but not until some unspecified time *after* the ceremony. You did not think about it until (some point in time) *after* the ceremony. But you did think of it.

So the sentence using *until after* is much more likely. The version with *before* is a perfectly valid statement, but it doesn't seem very useful. "I didn't think of it before the ceremony." "Okay, but when did you think of it? Or did you at all?" It just doesn't give much information.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence means that you could not have been thinking of it *during* the Ceremony of Twelve. The second sentence allows for that possibility, and in fact (at least in my opinion), suggests that you *did* think of it *during* the ceremony.

Also, and this is more speculative than the bit above, I think that the first sentence has more of an implication of a missed opportunity. If you say *until after*, that sounds like you thought of something, but it was too late. When you just say *before*, to me that is much more of an implication-free statement.